# Why is my Java circular matrix wrong?

Tags: java, matrix, spiral

i have a code what make a spirla matrix , but i'd like to write this matrix translated.
my output looks like :

```
1   2   3   
10  11  4   
9   12  5   
8   7   6
```

but this is wrong, because I'd like this:

```
4 5 6
3 12 7
2 11 8
1 10 9
```

It is my code:

```
public void generateMatrixFile(int n , int m){
    //n row, m column
     int A[][]=new int[n][m];
        int k=1, c1=0, c2=m-1, r1=0, r2=n-1;

        while(k<=n*m) {
                for(int i=c1;i<=c2;i++) {
                    A[r1][i]=k++;
                }
                for(int j=r1+1;j<=r2;j++) {
                    A[j][c2]=k++;
                }
                for(int i=c2-1;i>=c1;i--) {
                    A[r2][i]=k++;
                }
                for(int j=r2-1;j>=r1+1;j--) {
                    A[j][c1]=k++;
                }
             c1++;
             c2--;
             r1++;
             r2--;
        }
        System.out.println("The Matrix is:");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                        System.out.print(A[i][j]+ "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The program is simply doing the wrong thing. If you wrote it yourself it should be easy to change it to what it should do. Where do you have difficulties?

Comment: I've copied this code and i put into my code and changed it for myself.

Comment: Try to understand what the variables mean and what the various loops are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The approaches to fixing this problem are as follows:

- Change the way the matrix is filled, or
- Change the way the matrix is printed, or
- Make some combination of the above two approaches.

Since your desired output is a combination of translating the matrix and flipping around its dimensions, you need a combination approach: switch around `n` and `m`, and reverse the order of iteration of your first loop to get the desired output. You also need to modify the nested loops to stop once `k` reaches the `n*m` mark.

```
public static void generateMatrixFile(int n , int m) {
    int A[][] = new int[m][n]; // Switched m and n
    int k=1, c1=0, c2=n-1, r1=0, r2=m-1; // Switched m and n
    while (k<=n*m) {
        for (int i=c1;i<=c2 && k<=n*m;i++) {
            A[r1][i]=k++;
        }
        for(int j=r1+1;j<=r2 && k<=n*m;j++) {
            A[j][c2]=k++;
        }
        for(int i=c2-1;i>=c1 && k<=n*m;i--) {
            A[r2][i]=k++;
        }
        for(int j=r2-1;j>=r1+1 && k<=n*m;j--) {
            A[j][c1]=k++;
        }
        c1++;
        c2--;
        r1++;
        r2--;
    }
    System.out.println("The Matrix is:");
    for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--) {
        for(int j=0 ; j < m ; j++) {
            System.out.print(A[j][i]+ "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/EX4jt9)

Comment: This is almost perfect , but the output has a bit problem.
4 5 6 
3 12 7 
2 13 8 
1 10 9 

The second column is wierd a bit. 10 13 12.

Comment: @Bbeni Your small loops did not finish upon reaching `n*m`. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the order of the loops, and adjust the variables according.

```
    public static void generateMatrixFile(int n , int m){
//n row, m column
 int A[][]=new int[n][m];
    int k=1, c1=0, c2=m-1, r1=0, r2=n-1;

    while(k<=n*m)
        {
            for(int j=r2;j>=r1;j--)
            {
                A[j][c1]=k++;
            }
            for(int i=c1+1;i<=c2;i++)
            {
                A[r1][i]=k++;
            }

            for(int j=r1+1;j<=r2;j++)
            {
                A[j][c2]=k++;
            }

            for(int i=c2-1;i>=c1+1;i--)
            {
                A[r2][i]=k++;
            }



         c1++;
         c2--;
         r1++;
         r2--;

        }


    System.out.println("The Matrix is:");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(A[i][j]+ "\t");
                }
         System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Hope that helps.